# Синхронизированный рандом

Tags: c++, указатели, xor

Так как добрый день писать тут нельзя, он автоматически удаляется за ненадобностью, сразу приступлю к сути вопроса. Есть шаблонный класс ксора указателей, который сохраняет оригинальный адрес указателя и возвращает его с помощью операции ксора. Есть способы усложнить обход этой меры защиты от реверс инженерии и есть вещи способные заставить реверсера выстрелить себе в голову при попытке анализа.
Суть в том, что у меня есть 150 зашифрованных таким образом указателей и мне нужно для каждого из них сгенерировать рандомное число, которое должно быть синхронизировано в генерации ключей и в функции Xor. Нужно сгенерировать 150 случайных чисел во время компиляции и использовать их для генерации ключей и функции Xor. Еще раз, хочу обратить внимание на то, что при генерации ключей и функции Xor, числа должны быть одинаковые, функция ксор вызывается в почти каждой строке кода моей программы. Код класса и генерации ключей ниже:

```
template< typename T>
class C_DynamicXorPtr
{
public:
    uint64_t m_XorKey_0;
    uint64_t m_XorKey_1;

    __forceinline T& Xor( )
    {
        return *reinterpret_cast< T* >( ( m_XorKey_0 ^ m_XorKey_1 ) - рандомное_число_сгенерированное_при_компиляции );
    }
};
```

Создание ключей:

```
template< typename T >
VOID CreateXorPtr( C_DynamicXorPtr< T >* pXorPtr, void* pOriginalPtr )
{
    pXorPtr->m_XorKey_0 = RandomHash( );
    pXorPtr->m_XorKey_1 = ( pXorPtr->m_XorKey_0 ^ ( ( uint64_t )( pOriginalPtr ) + рандомное_число_сгенерированное_при_компиляции_) );
}
```

Comment: призывы к суициду? ну ну.

Comment: Это была ирония.

Comment: нормальный компилятор выбросит эту всю дребедень и будет прав. Хотите нормальную защиту - делайте внешнюю тулу, которая будет находить расставленные Вам метки и вписывать туда случайные числа.

Comment: CLang тулы и MSVS компилятор уважает такое

Comment: просто оптимизацию нужно включить.

Comment: /o2 включена и оптимизация фреймов

Comment: "Так как добрый день писать тут нельзя,..." издеваешься?

Comment: @НикитаСамоуков, здесь все можно, только если напишешь "нельзя".